# PhoneGap HTML slow animation

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, html5-canvas

i am testing an HTML5 canvas animation on Phonegap. first i programmed a web version of this simple animation (different shapes bouncing from side to side). the web version works fast and without any problems. on the other hand once i download the app using PhoneGap build the animation of the app is very slow.

i don't understand what is the problem, or maybe PhoneGap can not handle canvas animation.

any suggestions

```
var doChange = true;
window.onload=function(){

var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d');

document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
doChange = false;
}, false);

document.getElementById('Animate').addEventListener('click', function() {
doChange = true;
loop();
}, false);

var animObjects = [];


animObjects.push(new animCircle(ctx, 60, 70, 100, 'red', 2, 0));
animObjects.push(new animCircle(ctx, 500, 250, 110, 'blue', -0.5, 0.2));
animObjects.push(new animRectangle(ctx, 0, 90, 80,80, 'yellow', 3, 3));
animObjects.push(new animCloud(ctx,170,80,2,2));


loop();


function loop() {
if (doChange===true) {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);

    for(var i = 0, ao; ao = animObjects[i]; i++) {
        ao.update();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);

} else {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);

}
}

function animRectangle(ctx, x, y, XSize,YSize, color, dx, dy) {

var me = this;

this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.XSize = XSize;
this.XSize = XSize;
this.color = color;
this.dx = dx;
this.dy = dy;

var bool = 0;

this.update = function() {

    if (me.x < 0 || me.x > ctx.canvas.width-80){
        me.dx = -me.dx;
    }
    if (me.y < 50 || me.y > 200){
        me.dy = -me.dy;
    }
    me.x += me.dx;
    me.y += me.dy;

    render();
}

function render() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(me.x, me.y, me.XSize, me.XSize);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = me.color;
    ctx.fill();
}
return this;
}

function animCircle(ctx, x, y, r, color, stepX, stepY) {

var me = this;

this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.radius = r;
this.color = color;
this.stepX = stepX;
this.stepY = stepY;

this.update = function() {
    me.x += me.stepX;
    me.y += me.stepY;
    if (me.x < 0 || me.x > ctx.canvas.width) me.stepX = -me.stepX;
    if (me.y < 0 || me.y > ctx.canvas.height) me.stepY = -me.stepY;

    render();
}

function render() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(me.x, me.y, me.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = me.color;
    ctx.fill();
}
return this;
}

function animCloud(ctx,x,y,dx,dy) {

var me = this;

this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.dx = dx;
this.dy = dy;

this.update = function() {

    if (me.x < -150 || me.x > ctx.canvas.width-420){
        me.dx = -me.dx;
    }
    if (me.y < 50 || me.y > 200){
        me.dy = -me.dy;
    }
    me.x += me.dx;
    me.y += me.dy;


    render();
}

function render() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(me.x+170, me.y+80);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(130+me.x, 100+me.y, 130+me.x, 150+me.y, 230+me.x, 150+me.y);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(250+me.x, 180+me.y, 320+me.x, 180+me.y, 340+me.x, 150+me.y);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(420+me.x, 150+me.y, 420+me.x, 120+me.y, 390+me.x, 100+me.y);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(430+me.x, 40+me.y, 370+me.x, 30+me.y, 340+me.x, 50+me.y);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(320+me.x, 5+me.y, 250+me.x, 20+me.y, 250+me.x, 50+me.y);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(200+me.x, 5+me.y, 150+me.x, 20+me.y, 170+me.x, 80+me.y);

    // complete custom shape
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.stroke();
}
return this;
}
}
```

Comment: Phonegap is just awfully slow.

Comment: is there any other way i can do this @Ahmad

Comment: Could you make a simple working version of this in jsbin.com? I'm struggling to figure out what exactly you are doing.

Comment: @GauntFace i am animating different shapes http://jsbin.com/AHorInEj/2/edit

Comment: Which Android version do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webview that is being used by the Native apps (in your case Phonegap uses Webview to load your HTML/JS app) is not the same as the browsers you use. So the sophisticated browser features and performance optimizations are not available in WebView. It is simply a bare bone implementation.

You can't do much about the WebView. You could still try and optimize your code base which would still not give much improvement in performace.

Good news though, is that in Android 4.4 (Kitkat) Google has replaced the older webview with chromium powered Webview. This means that you have features and performance that you had in your chrome browser will now be available in your webview also. http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/11/02/kitkats-webview-powered-chromium-enabling-android-app-developers-use-new-html5-css-features/

Comment: Does Phonegap automatically take advantage of the new chromium powered webview, or do you need to configure something to take advantage of it?

Comment: Yes, It will take advantage of the new Webview. Because the Phonegap simply extends the WebView and other related classes provided by Android API. But there were some bugs that were reported in versions  prior to 3.3.0 running in Kitkat. The official support for Kitkat is now available in the phonegap's latest release [3.3.0](http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/12/13/phonegap-release/).

Comment: Beware people, the implementation of the webview in KitKat has a bug regarding hardware acceleration, and is extremly slow: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=315111

Comment: Yup they gave the "performance" increase by taking away hardware acceleration without the possibility to use the old WebView. And also they don't seem to prioritize the issue. Now Phonegap and similar have no future with this unusable rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an alternative, you might want to use GeckoView...

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView

It is an android library for rendering html5 apps.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I thought this could help. I ran into the same issue a month ago and I ended up finding the [Crosswalk Project](https://crosswalk-project.org/#wiki/Create-Sample-App-With-Crosswalk-Cordova-Android) which merges with PhoneGap (Cordova) and changes the webview from the "native" Android browser to a Chromium-based one. Animations run beautifully on it. I really suggest using it for future projects.